# After Primefaces Validation not able to input anything in Form?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This is my form ..

```
<p:panel id="panel" header="Portfolio Transaction">
            <p:messages id="msgs" />

            <p:panelGrid columns="7" id="transactionPanel" style="display: inline-block;">
                <f:facet name="header"> 
                    Register New Trade
                </f:facet>

                <h:outputLabel for="tipsSuggestionBoxId" value="Company Name:*"></h:outputLabel>

                <h:outputText value="Date:*" />

                <h:outputText value="Type:*" />

                <h:outputText value="Quantity:*" />

                <h:outputText value="Price:*" />

                <h:outputText value="Brokerage:" />

                <h:outputText value="Notes:" />

                <p:autoComplete id="tipsSuggestionBoxId"
                    completeMethod="#{portfolioTransactionBean.autoSelectCompany}"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.companyName}"
                    minChars="3" nothingLabel="No similar company found"
                    requestDelay="1" minQueryLength="3" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Company Name Cannot be empty">
                </p:autoComplete>

                <p:calendar id="from_date" size="10" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Date Cannot be empty"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptTransDate}"
                    mode="popup" showOn="both" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                    popupIconOnly="true" readonly="#{facesContext.renderResponse}">
                </p:calendar>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="tranType"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptTransType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Transaction Type" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Buy" itemValue="Buy" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sell" itemValue="Sell" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>


                <p:spinner id="transQuntity" required="true"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptQty}" min="1"    label="Quanity" size="5"
                    validatorMessage="Field Is mandatory" />

                <p:spinner id="transPrice" required="true" size="5"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptPrice}"
                    label="Price"
                    validatorMessage="Field Is mandatory" />



                <p:spinner id="brokerage" size="5"
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptBrokerage}"  />

                <h:inputText
                    value="#{portfolioTransactionBean.txnCurrentRecord.umptNotes}" />

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton value="Save Transaction " icon="ui-icon-check"
                        action="#{portfolioTransactionBean.savePortfolioTransaction}"
                        update="panel" style="float:right;right:20%;">
                        <p:resetInput target="transactionPanel" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:spacer width="100" height="10" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Clear" update="transactionPanel"
                        process="@this">
                        <p:resetInput target="transactionPanel" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>


            </p:panelGrid>
```

after form validation fail like user not input date or company name , i am able to see proper message but after that i am not able to input any value from keybord.Any one know what is the issue with code.

This problem not occurring only when validation fail even when i clicked on clear button i am getting same issue. Any one get this issue?

Comment: How do you mean unable? Are the input components greyed out or are they enabled but keyboard input doesn't reflect on-screen? Try moving the `<p:commandButton/>` outside of the facet or outside of the panel altogether

Comment: I  am not able to input any thing in textbox,spinner,date from keyboard even i put command button outside panel

Comment: Interesting. Try to compare the state of the HTML markup around the panel before and after the resetInput operation. I also hope you don't have a nesting of `<h:form/>`s in there

Comment: I am using 2 layer template but only one <h:form>

Comment: Have you tried on another browser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true for some components in primefaces. The only solution is trying using some other components which replaces the problamatic components. or other wise if there is some error show the error , and write a code which refreshes entire screen if user gets an error message. Ofcourse the user needs to enter all details again.